# Сформировать SQL запрос (Агрегатные ф-ии)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть 3 таблицы: detail, stock, accounting
[image: Поля и связи таблиц]

Посредством SqlTableAdapter вывожу различные запросы пользователей (через инпуты).

Сейчас потребовалось задать такой запрос, чтобы вывелись все детали такие, что:
имеются сведения о наличии этой детали на некотором складе в количестве > 100
и каждая отгрузка этой детали с этого склада была в количестве > 200.

[100 и 200 это понятно спонтанные значения, которые в дальнейшем заменятся @var1 @var2]

По-разному пытался вывести результаты, постоянно получаю что-то не то. 
Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос

```
select a.detail_id, sum(a.quantity), b.quantity from STOCK as a, ACCOUNTING as b
where (a.QUANTITY > 100) 
group by a.DETAIL_ID 
having b.QUANTITY > 200
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

пусть

**detail.id[0] = 1, stock.stock_num[0]=1**, stock.quantity[0] = 125, accounting.quantity[0] = 1230;

detail.id[ 1 ] = 2, stock.stock_num[ 1 ]=5, stock.quantity[ 1 ] = 50, accounting.quantity[ 1 ] = 60;

detail.id[2] = 3, stock.stock_num[2]=3, stock.quantity[2] = 135, accounting.quantity[2] = 1200;

**detail.id[3] = 1, stock.stock_num[3]=2**, stock.quantity[3] = 145, accounting.quantity[3] = 1300

Тогда в выводе должны отобразиться суммы [0] и [2] и [3] элементов (так-как в [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUTj9.png) элементе не попадает в условие)

И в выводе получаем что-то вроде этого:

**id** **sock_Quantity Accounting_Quantity**

1______170______________2530_______

3______135______________1200_______

Comment: где 170 = SUM(stock.quantity[0] = 125, stock.quantity[3] = 145). 2530 = SUM(accounting.quantity[0] = 1230, accounting.quantity[3] = 1300)

Answer (score 0):

У вас связь один(`STOCK`)-ко-многим(`ACCOUNTING`), значит группировать по `a.DETAIL_ID` и суммировать `a.quantity`, когда присоединили еще таблицу `ACCOUNTING` будет неправильным. Правильнее будет по отдельности сгруппировать таблицу `ACCOUNTING` по `DETAIL_ID` и `STOCK_NUM`, а затем уже соединять его с таблицей `STOCK`. Примерно так:

```
SELECT a.detail_id
  , sum(a.quantity)
  , b.SUM_QUANTITY
FROM STOCK as a
JOIN (SELECT STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_QUANTITY FROM ACCOUNTING GROUP BY STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID) AS b ON a.STOCK_NUM = b.STOCK_NUM AND a.DETAIL_ID = b.DETAIL_ID
WHERE b.SUM_QUANTITY > 200
GROUP BY a.DETAIL_ID 
  , b.SUM_QUANTITY
HAVING SUM(a.QUANTITY) > 100
```

Если деталь (`DETAIL_ID`) может присутствовать на разных складах (судя по первоначальному запросу автора), то скорее так:

```
SELECT a.detail_id
  , sum(a.quantity)
  , SUM(b.SUM_QUANTITY)
FROM STOCK as a
JOIN (SELECT STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_QUANTITY FROM ACCOUNTING GROUP BY STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID) AS b ON a.STOCK_NUM = b.STOCK_NUM AND a.DETAIL_ID = b.DETAIL_ID
GROUP BY a.DETAIL_ID 
  , b.SUM_QUANTITY
HAVING SUM(a.QUANTITY) > 100 AND SUM(b.SUM_QUANTITY) > 200
```

**ДОПОНЕНИЕ**

Судя по дополнению автора, не совсем понятно применение группировки и фильтр по сгруппированным данным. Насколько понятно по дополнениям, фильтрация записей необходима до группировки. Тогда логично использовать либо `EXISTS`, либо в подзапросах фильтровать `STOCK` и `ACCOUNTING` и затем уже соединив их сгруппировать.
Либо например так:

```
SELECT a.detail_id
  , sum(a.quantity)
  , b.SUM_QUANTITY
FROM STOCK as a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID, QUANTITY  FROM ACCOUNTING WHERE STOCK_NUM = a.STOCK_NUM AND DETAIL_ID = a.DETAIL_ID AND QUANTITY > 200) AS b
WHERE a.QUANTITY > 100
GROUP BY a.DETAIL_ID
```

Comment: и вылетает вечная ошибка: 
Столбец "b.SUM_QUANTITY" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Comment: Подправил. Но тут скорее тогда `SUM(b.SUM_QUANTITY)` - если detail_id может присутствовать в разных складах

Comment: получается не совсем тот запрос. В HAVING - е мы сравниваем сумму с числом 100 и 200. А надо получить сумму тех элементов, которые содержатся на конкретном складе в количестве больше 100. Т.е. если на i-ом складе количество k-ой детали больше 100 и ее отгрузка в кол-ве большем 200, то sum += a.quantity, sum2 += b.quantity

Comment: То есть, нужно в выборке показать в разрезе *конкретных* складов по *конкретным* деталям? Тогда вам в выборке выводить также идентификаторы склада, то есть группировать не только по `DETAIL_ID`, но еще и по `STOCK_NUM`, тогда второй запрос с моего ответа должен подойти

Comment: Добавил дополнеие.Как происходит вывод в вопрос выше